# Making and edit form - How set default input values in a CreatableSelect (React-select)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am making an edit form for API documents. Two of the inputs are select types, one of which is a CreatableSelect that can have multiple inputs. When I bring in the document and set it as the state it is stored in I am not sure how to prepopulate this type of input to allow a user to reference and edit. The data is stored as an array of strings but the options of the CreatableSelect is stored as objects with a label and value.

Incoming doc stores the creatable multi select data like so:

```
tags: ['Offbeat', 'sculpture']
```

CreatableSelect takes in options as an array of objects like this plus many more:

```
{label: 'Offbeat', value: 'Offbeat'}
{label: 'sculpture', value: 'sculpture'}
```

The option data is brought in as an array of string and I convert them into an array of objects like above to be options of the CreatableSelect.

I am making an edit route for the documents and want see the selected array items pre-populating the input on the form so user can add or remove options. I have tried using `defaultValue` prop of `<CreatableSelect>`

```
<Form.Group className='mb-2'>
      <Form.Label htmlFor='tags'>Edit/Add Tags?</Form.Label>
      {defaultMultiSelect && <CreatableSelect
        isClearable
        isMulti
        options={allTagsStructured}
        onChange={(value) => handleMultiCreateChange('tags', value)}
        defaultValue={[{label: 'sculpture', value: 'sculpture'}, {label: 'offbeat', value: 'offbeat'}]}
        defaultInputValue={'art'}
      />}
```

Between defaultValue and defaultInputValue, the former gave me the output I am looking for but to make the form dynamic I am trying to create a variable of the preselected options to place into the `defaultValue` prop.

```
const [defaultMultiSelect, setDefaultMultiSelect] = useState([])
const [defaultTypeSelect, setDefaultTypeSelect] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      console.log(id)
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/pins/${id}`)
        console.log(data)
        setFormData(data)
        handleIncomingtags(data.tags)
        handleIncomingType(data.typeOfPlace)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
    getData()
  }, [id])

  const handleIncomingtags = (tags) => {
    const selectOptions = []
    tags.map(tag => {
      const obj = {}
      obj.label = tag
      obj.value = tag
      return selectOptions.push(obj)
    })
    setDefaultMultiSelect(selectOptions)
    console.log(selectOptions)
    console.log(defaultMultiSelect)
  }

  const handleIncomingType = (type) => {
    const selectOptions = []
    type.map(oneType => {
      const obj = {}
      obj.label = oneType
      obj.value = oneType
      return selectOptions.push(obj)
    })
    setDefaultTypeSelect(selectOptions)
    console.log(defaultTypeSelect)
  }
```

This saves an array of options of the document that I want to be in the select input:

```
[{label: 'Bar', value: 'Bar'}, {label: 'Gaming', value: 'Gaming'}, {label: 'Social', value: 'Social'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const [defaultMultiSelect, setDefaultMultiSelect] = useState([])
```

The default of the state is an empty array which is a truthy value, it should be set to a falsey value otherwise it will trigger a render on load before any the data comes in:

```
const [defaultMultiSelect, setDefaultMultiSelect] = useState(null)
```